# Where is the manadatory parameter in this restAPI method?

Tags: powershell, rest

I am learning how to use restAPIs, I am using RegEx101s API to carry out tests,  in their [documentation](https://github.com/firasdib/Regex101/wiki/API#list-andor-search-all-library-entries-) for their **Search** method, they state that the method has at least one mandatory parameter, which is the `page number` parameter, its supposed to control for the amount of search results returned.

Bu when I use this method and specify different value for `page number`, the returned results are the same:

```
$uri            = "https://regex101.com/api/library/1/?filterFlavors=python"
$response   = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri
($response.data).count
```

The above call returns `20` and so does this as well:

```
$uri            = "https://regex101.com/api/library/5/?filterFlavors=python"    # from "1" to "5"
$response   = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri
($response.data).count
```

What am I could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: The documentation says _"If submitted page number is beyond what is available, the highest page number results are returned instead."_ - so (depending on the query/request) you'll get the same results for `/api/5/...` and you will for `/api/99999/...`

Comment: @Dai I completely misread that example then, so this means they have exactly 20 resilts that have 'python'  flavours on their site? that does not seem right, I will try verify manually on their site tomorrow morning. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: What is that `.count` property you're using? It doesn't appear in their documentation.

Comment: @Dai its just Powershell syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: If you use the Same API URL in the browser, you will get actual results.. I have used the same URL (https://regex101.com/api/library/1/?filterFlavors=python) that you have used in the script. you will get the results in text format.. Consider below is the example]

If you use the Same API URL in the browser, you will get actual results.. I have used the same URL (https://regex101.com/api/library/1/?filterFlavors=python) that you have used in the script. you will get the results in text format.. Consider attached image as the example and the proof having 20 Python strings.. also the correct syntax as below

```
 $uri            = "https://regex101.com/api/library/1/?search=Most+recent"
$response   = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method get
($response.data).count
```

Comment: This is perfect, also I did not know you could open the url in the browser. Very neat trick. Thank you!